# Update Custom Forms with Powershell

Tags: infopath, form, powershell

I'm trying to **update custom forms** of SharePoint lists in a large amount of SharePoint 2010 subsites with **powershell**.

I'm not quite sure what the correct approach is. The form itself can be found as template.xsn in the Item Folder of the corresponding SharePoint list.

Does the publish process of InfoPath more than change this file? I tested only copying the file and no errors happend. But this doesn't mean that *no* database inconsistencies occured. I'm not to keen on any misfortunes, that might happen later.

Now, my approach would simply be to copy the current custom form as file (Item\template.xsn) in the list of each subsite.

So now my question is;

- What is the best approach to update subsites with an *old* custom form with powershell?
- Can I use the approach described above?

Comment: How were the forms deployed originally? Powershell, a WSP, console app, something else? Just curious if you can leverage what you already have as a starting point to make it meet your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Do the forms contain any other references, such as lookup lists, or SharePoint data connections ?   Within the contents of the form (InfoPath), these might need to be verified/checked - when the InfoPath client does the 'publish'.